# fetchrow_array returns extra 0 in the end

Tags: perl, stored-procedures, sybase

I am calling the sybase stored proc below from perl

```
create  procedure  testprocedure2 as 
begin
  select 'one'
end
GO
```

In perl I use DBI

```
do {
      while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
            print $row[0]."\n";
      }
  } while ($sth->{syb_more_results});
```

As a result, I get

```
One
0
```

Why am i getting an extra 0 in the end?

Comment: which module are you using for sybase?

Comment: I think you have to look at `$sth->{syb_result_type}` and ignore the result types in which you aren't interested. See DBD::Sybase's docs for the possible values

Comment: @ikegami Thanks alot, been stuck on it for a long time.

Comment: Also see [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.mainframeconnect_12.6.occprc/html/occprc/X12699.htm) which describes the result types a little. But do read DBD::Sybase too.

Comment: @ikegami you can put that in the answer, and I'll accept and close this thread

Comment: Only because you asked, since I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a quick look around the web, I'm guessing you have to look at `$sth->{syb_result_type}` and ignore the result types in which you aren't interested.

Read both the docs for [DBD::Sybase](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::Sybase) (which documents `$sth->{syb_result_type}`) and [this](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.mainframeconnect_12.6.occprc/html/occprc/X12699.htm) (which describes the result types a little).

I think the `0` is the `CS_STATUS_RESULT`, the result of the stored procedure. I think I found corroboration that zero indicates success.